# Angular cache interceptors vs service level caching?

Tags: angular, caching

Is it better to cache data using `interceptors` like explianied in the [offitial doc](https://angular.io/guide/http#caching) or it's better to handle it in the service level to have more controle ?

Comment: what do you have in mind by `handle it in the service level`?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com I cache model objects in a service, and the same cached object is shared upon different components. I am wondering about the best practices when to clone or not an object. I am clonning only when dealing with forms to prevent changes caused by two way data binding